# How do I visualize social networks with Python

Tags: python, graph, social-graph

I need to define a [social network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network), analyze it and draw it. I could both draw it by hand and analyze it (calculate various metrics) by hand. But I would not like to reinvent the wheel.

I have tried to use matplotlib, but I need to use it interactively, and in a few lines tell it how to load the data, and then call a render function, that will render the graph as a SVG.

How can I visualize social networks in the described way?

Comment: Wow. I do NOT like the way you edited my post, Bhargav Rao! I generally like the freedom to improve questions written by others, and perhaps you did improve in some way though I am not able to see that. 1) You deleted essential parts (fx "analyze", now it says only "visualize") 2) You added non-essential things that I never meant to say "But I would not like to reinvent the wheel. ". 3) You added poor language "But I would not like to reinvent the wheel. ", should be "would like not to reinvent".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*[networkx](http://networkx.github.com/)* is a very powerful and flexible Python library for working with network graphs. Directed and undirected connections can be used to connect nodes. Networks can be constructed by adding nodes and then the edges that connect them, or simply by listing edge pairs (undefined nodes will be automatically created). Once created, nodes (and edges) can be annotated with arbitrary labels.

Although *networkx* can be used to visualise a network (see the documentation), you may prefer to use a network visualisation application such as *Gephi* (available from [gephi.org](http://gephi.org)). *networkx* supports a wide range of import and export formats. If you export a network using a format such as *GraphML*, the exported file can be easily loaded into *Gephi* and visualised there.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(3,4)])
G
>>> <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x128a930>
G.nodes(data=True)
>>> [(1, {}), (2, {}), (3, {}), (4, {})]
G.node[1]['attribute']='value'
G.nodes(data=True)
>>> [(1, {'attribute': 'value'}), (2, {}), (3, {}), (4, {})]
nx.write_graphml(G,'so.graphml')
```

Comment: how to fetch this n/w graph to html via ajax call?

Answer (score 19):

There are three answers that mention Networkx and Gephi, but no one mentioned [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/). The main difference is that the algorithms are implemented in C++, giving a [performance boost](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance) compared to e.g. Networkx.

And, it also covers visualization. From the site:

> Conveniently draw your graphs, using a variety of algorithms and
>   output formats (including to the screen). Graph-tool has its own
>   layout algorithms and versatile, interactive drawing routines based on
>   cairo and GTK+, but it can also work as a very comfortable interface
>   to the excellent graphviz package.

Here's a neat example [from the docs](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/community.html) (there are many many more):

[image: Block partition of a political blogs network]

(Block partition of a political blogs network).

And, the code for it:

```
>>> g = gt.collection.data["polblogs"]
>>> g = gt.GraphView(g, vfilt=gt.label_largest_component(gt.GraphView(g, directed=False)))
>>> state = gt.BlockState(g, B=g.num_vertices(), deg_corr=True)
>>> state = gt.multilevel_minimize(state, B=2)
>>> gt.graph_draw(g, pos=g.vp["pos"], vertex_fill_color=state.get_blocks(), output="polblogs_agg.pdf")
<...>
```

<sub>(Note: The positions of each node is predetermined in this example, so no layout algorithm had to be run)</sub>

Here's another example using the same data (and the result is incredible):
http://ryancompton.net/2014/10/05/graph-tools-visualization-is-pretty-good/

Comment: `output="polblogs_agg.pdf"` would be a problem if one has to embed these graphs into an html page? possible to return `html` or `div`??

Comment: @NoobEditor see [the docs](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html?highlight=output): `fmt : Output file format. Possible values are "auto", "ps", "pdf", "svg", and "png". If the value is "auto", the format is guessed from the output parameter.'`

So just name it e.g. .png for example and you'll get a png. Then the next step is to include this image in your html.

Comment: installing graphtool in 2017 on a mac is impossible. requires os x mavericks

Answer (score 12):

**A lot has happened here recently!** [Netwulf](https://github.com/benmaier/netwulf/) is a library dedicated to enabling easy reproducible interactive visualization of networks in Python (disclaimer: I'm a contributor).

[image: img]

Also check out [webweb](https://github.com/dblarremore/webweb), which is better if you want to export the network as html.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/). You might use with gml files too.

Like psychemedia said, you can use Networkx to plot your graph and to export to gml file.

```
nx.write_graphml(G,'my_file.gml')
```

After that, in Cytoscape click on From Network File and select your gml file. There, you can change the style too.

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here at Stack Overflow.  Instead, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include a basic example of using Cytoscape for social networks.

Comment: I'm sorry, drs. But I just completed other answers. I'll be better.